# Bending 1/2" emt conduit

Tags: electrical

Why am i having problems bending an offset on the 2nd marker for an 1 inch marker for 10 degrees? Either I'm weak or is there a chart for using 10 degrees, 22.5 degrees, 30 degrees, etc for the appropriate inches to match the degrees to bend. i followed what was on my Klein bender. Which is 6 1/16 (including shrinkage) apart. I did make a 90 degree first on a five foot pipe. So please any advise will be appreciated. I look at youtube videos but it doesn't address this problem. And yes it was perpendicular from my body with my foot holding the bottom of the bender against my right foot. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your problem with bending the conduit? Are you not able to get the bend started?

Comment: Are you making the offset at the end of the pipe ?  Or are you making a saddle bend offset. As suggested below uglys is a good guide and cheap.

Comment: Thank you.it is at the end of a bend approximately 13 inches and no it isn't a saddle bend.  I cant  even budge the bend for the offset on the second marker after turning 180 degrees around. I did get it started on the first marker with no problem but when i go to the second marker 6 1/16 it wouldn't budge.  Remember i made a 90 on the other end. I also will get the app that was suggested as well.

Comment: Is it called conduit bender elite?

Comment: When making such small bends we have the bender in a standing position with the head up instead of on the floor. Then grip the conduit tightly and make the bend closest to the end of the pipe first, then rotate the conduit 180º and make the second bend.

Comment: I normally just use 6 as a multiplier for a 10º bend and tweek it accordingly for a ⅜" box offset or small offsets like that.

Comment: Thats where i probably went wrong. The bender was standing but i wasnt at the end trying to pull down. I always thought you where suppose to put it underyour arm. But your way would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your last comment, it sounds like you are trying to make the following bend by doing the 90-degree bend followed by the bump-out and you are unable complete the bend for the bump-out.

[image: Attempted Bend]

This basically comes down to finding a way to get more leverage.

One way to accomplish this is to plan out the order of the bends better so you are not pulling on short lengths of conduit or in ways that the conduit will want to rotate on you. In this case, I would suggest one of the following workflows:

1. Reverse the order of the bends: Do the bump out followed by the 90 degree bend.
2. Depending on the length of conduit required after the 90 degree bend on the side opposite of the bump-out, start by making the bends further toward the middle of the conduit so that you have a long piece of conduit to work with on the side with the bump-out. Then, you cut off the excess length you do not need:

[image: Potential alternate bending workflow]

Comment: Thank you for explaining and showing me. I will do that from this point on. Your diagram was exactly what i was suppose to have accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

There is a book that most electricians are familiar with called [Ugly's](http://www.uglysbooks.com/proddetail.php?prod=978-1284119367). It has all kind of information including you bending problem. If you want something more modern. I have an app called Conduit Bend or it might be Conduit Elite Bend. Its excellent app for what you are wanting.

Comment: Last question--i did purchase Ugly's but it only show basic offsets 1/2" emt bends. It doesn't explain how to do the opposite of a raise bend to a lower or even a side bend. Or a back to back but doesn't show how to do an opposite bend. For example like the great diagram that was made for me (by the way your suggestion perfectly worked) and lets say with that first offset before  the 90, i wanted to put an obstacle bend that instead of making a saddle to make a snake around it? Do you need to change position (reposition) of the conduit if it was snaked? Thank you all for helping me.